# Select unique records by comapring one column values in a particular order in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a Table with columns (status, timestamp and other) like below:
I want to fetch all records where status is changing order by date desc

[image: source Data]

response should be like :

[image: response Data]

Comment: What does mean other columns? which column need for grouping? timestamp?

Comment: Don't look at other columns.. , id is the primary key, status Is what i am interested in to compare ( with previous) and date/ timestamp to sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and only keep the rows where the value changes:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (order by date) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status
order by date desc;
```